# A word for stretching out the facts just so they fit a theory?

Tags: psychology

There’s *pareidolia* which describes the phenomenon of your brain tricking you into seeing faces in every-day objects.

There’s also a (seemingly) related phenomenon of people believing in a theory so hard that they stretch the facts or even make them up just so that they fit the theory.

Does this phenomenon/behaviour have a name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phenomenon you describe is a type of ***cognitive bias***. This particular bias of stretching facts to fit your theory is called ***confirmation bias***, defined as

> The tendency to search for or interpret information in a way that confirms one's preconceptions. In addition, individuals may discredit information that does not support their views. ([here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_bias))

and

> the tendency to search for, interpret, favor, and recall information in a way that confirms one's preexisting beliefs or hypotheses, while giving disproportionately less consideration to alternative possibilities. ([here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias))

These definitions don't explicitly mention *making up* facts to fit one's theory, but any person who did this could certainly be said to be *biased toward confirmation*. This suggest that the term can also be used to describe the (possibly accidental) fabrication of "confirming facts".